# ckeditor LINK is not working in jQuery Dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, ckeditor

I am using **CKEditor Version 3.3.1,** Also tried latest **version 4.3** but facing same problem.

Now the problem is, Whenever I try to load the CKEDITOR to the Textarea Which is located inside the jQuery Dialog box, CKEditor loads properly, but When I try to create a hyper link, It open up the Link Popup box, but Link options (**Input field, dropdown etc**) is not working.

For reference[image] see the attached screen shot.
Please guide me, how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you checked the Z-Indexes of the elements? I find this is usually because the z-index for a child is smaller than that of a cousin or something.

Comment: Yes, I have checked the z-indexes too, but z-index is not the solving problem, some searches says, it because of not properly destroying the CKEditor instance, I tried that too... but no luck...

Whenever I create the textarea on plain page (**means no jQuery Dialog box**) and apply the CKEditor, everything works fine, but it giving the problem with Dialog box. :(

Comment: Are you able to create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Here is the jsFiddle link [JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/twv7e/6/) , I just created, it having the same problem

Comment: I believe [this](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/5779) is relevant to your cause and may help you

Comment: Here is the solution for the above problem, thats worked for me. [click Here](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9087#comment:30)

Comment: JSFiddle Demo link: http://jsfiddle.net/qazihamayun/LUg42/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the solution for the above problem, thats worked for me.

[Solution for CKEditor Popup in a jQuery Dialog Box](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9087#comment:30)

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, but in my case Textarea belonged to a modal window.

Removing "tabindex="-1"" was fixed.

Comment: What do you mean by "Removing "tabindex="-1"" was fixed."?
Did **you** remove tabindex=-1, or did someone else fix something?

Answer (score 4):

I have solved it by setting z-index to a bigger value than my bootstrap modal:

```
 .ck.ck-balloon-panel {
        z-index: 1050 !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Fixed using the following thread. It saved me lots of time:

[Twitter bootstrap problem with ckeditor dialogue in modal](http://ckeditor.com/comment/127719#comment-127719)

Answer (score 2):

Same issue here, but using other frameworks.
In short I was using modal divs.

Then I found out that one of them had a `tabindex` attribute defined. Once I removed it CKEDITOR started working as expected.

**No modal** should have `tabindex` attribute defined.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem is related to modal structure which text area is located inside the this jQuery Dialog box that has `tabindex` attribute like below:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modal">
   // text area is here in this modal body
</div>
```

By removing `tabindex="1"` you can change link textbox in Link Popup box in ckeditor.